# Least costly way to update a ComputedProperty when child models are updated?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a data model with parent-child relationships structured as such:

```
Container
  Metric
    Value
```

Each of these models has a "status" field, but only the Value model allows input on that field; the other models have a ComputedProperty that changes based on the "status" field in their ancestor Value models.  As it stands, I get current results on the parents when the model is read directly (just like @property behavior), but stale results when the model is part of a query.

So I need to update the parent models' "status" field when the child model's status is updated.  I know I could put a `_post_put_hook()` in the Value model and just `put()` all parents whenever it's updated, but that seems expensive.

- Is there a way to have the parents "watch" the children?
- Is there a less expensive workaround for querying the parents on the "status" property? (so I don't have to use ComputedProperty)
- Am I using too many models?  Should I just be mashing them together as StructuredProperties so that one put() puts all?  (although I've had problems with that as well updating the parent's status before the child's)
- Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

For indexes you get eventual consistency, meaning that they usually update within a second or so, but there is no guarantee.

With your current design (depending on your consistency requirements) you might have to do the status updates transactionally, perhaps using the _pre_put_hook (which hopefully enables you to start transaction). It's 3 writes, but there is no way of getting around that if you have to update 3 nested entities in entity group.

I don't think there is any kind of "watch" or automatic event/trigger handling available.

If this is always a 1:1 relationship it might make sense to make this into a single object, which always has status. Potential disadvantage would be that you have to write everything back every time you update, which is more overhead for big objects. Advantage is the ability to query on any property.

If you need to query on status and other properties on every level you need status everywhere, otherwise you can move status to the entity where it has to be available for querying.

If you only query on status and not other properties of Container or Metric, you can do something like

```
[value_key.parent().parent().get() for value_key in Value.query().get(keys_only=True)]
```

to get a list of Containers from a Value query.

Comment: Hm...I didn't think about the index thing.  Right now, I'm not querying on status, but I will be eventually.  So maybe once the indexes get built, it'll fix the whole issue; that'd be cool.  Eventual consistency is fine for this (I think).  For now, I'm leaving them nested with the hooks, but I incorrectly used `_post_put_hook()`.  I'll switch to `_pre_put_hook()` within a transaction.  I'm using mostly ancestor queries right now (which are awesome!), but I'll keep the "reverse-ancestor" query I want to call it? in mind for the future.  Thanks!